# Does rebuilding/reorganize an index in SQL Server free up space in the DB file due to compacting data pages?

Tags: sql-server, index, storage, shrink

If I have an index with a default fill factor of 100%, and modifications result in a large amount of internal fragmentation (page splits, free space, etc.) so that many pages end up around 60% full instead of 100%, would an index rebuild/reorganize compact the data into fewer data pages, thus resulting in more available space reported in the database?

If the previous is true, does it then make sense to reorganize indexes before performing a shrink operation to maximize the space gained by the shrink (followed by another reorganize after the shrink to reduce fragmentation caused by the shrink)?

Finally, does DBCC Shrinkfile compact data pages the way a rebuild does, or does it only move data pages around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would an index rebuild/reorganize compact the data into fewer data
> pages, thus resulting in more available space reported in the
> database?

Yes. You are correct.

> maximize the space gained by the shrink

Usually it doesn't worth the efforts.

> followed by another reorganize after the shrink to reduce
> fragmentation caused by the shrink

All operations: shrink and reorg are pretty expensive so it doesn't make sense to run them 'just in case'.

> does DBCC Shrinkfile compact data pages the way a rebuild does, or
> does it only move data pages around?

It only moves data pages.

From my point of view you are fighting for space (cheapest resource for modern databases) by CPU, memory and network bandwidth (more expensive ones)

Comment: Thank you, this answers everything. Agreed on your last point regarding fighting for space. I have to work with limited storage at the moment so I'm trying to optimize this process as much as possible. Now that I know that regaining some extra available space from a reorganize is possible on paper, I'll test it to see what the potential gains are.

Answer (score 0):

> would an index rebuild/reorganize compact the data into fewer data pages, thus resulting in more available space reported in the database?

The purpose of index maintenance is to reduce index fragmentation, not save space. But in its process it needs to utilize available space that's almost twice the size of the index to do the actual reorganization of the data in it. So effectively index maintenance is wasteful and consumes more space.

It's also a waste of an operation and almost never needed. It's heavy, causes resource contention, and any perceived performance gains from it are actually from secondary related processes that occur (statistics updates and clearing query plans from the cache) that can be ran individually and separately.

> If the previous is true, does it then make sense to reorganize indexes before performing a shrink operation to maximize the space gained by the shrink

Big nope. Shrinking causes indexes to re-fragment, undoing most of the work you just spent on doing index maintenance. They're counterintuitive to each other.

Also, shrinking is a heavy operation that can cause resource contention too, and should rarely be used. It's meant for only special one-off cases.

Here's some related resources from experts:

1. [Index Maintenance Madness](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/index-maintenance-madness/)
2. [Stop Shrinking Your Database Files. Seriously. Now.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/)

Comment: Agreed on most points. But the storage space available to me is very limited so needs must sometimes. Regarding fragmentation post-shrink, I usually resolve that with a reorganize (which only grows out the transaction log and is easily shrinkable).

Comment: @Marcus Storage space is cheap, slow databases aren't. But to each their own. Shrinking I don't have as much of a problem with. Index maintenance is something that should just straight up be removed from the product though. "*Regarding fragmentation post-shrink, I usually resolve that with a reorganize (which only grows out the transaction log and is easily shrinkable).*" - Heh, you realize you just said you'll shrink your database to save space but run index maintenance to regrow it to fix fragmentation but then shrink it again to fix the growth which will now result in fragmentation again?

Comment: ^...it's a vicious cycle that doesn't actually help you and a trap people fall into, as discussed in some of the articles I mentioned and other related articles on there. Thanks for listening to my TED Talk, feel free to upvote if you desire, so others may find it helpful as well.

Comment: I'm shrinking the data file initially – the follow up index maintenance will only grow the log file which can be shrunk easily. This leaves the DB occupying a smaller size than before sans fragmentation. It can be cyclical for DBs that are expected to grow again, but sometimes it's necessary because of storage space constraints. I agree index maintenance isn't worth the effort in most cases, but if I can avoid 99% fragmentation on all tables post a required shrink then it's not an issue.

Comment: @Marcus That's a lot of unneeded *heavy* work against your database. I guess resource contention isn't a concern though. "*but if I can avoid 99% fragmentation on all tables post a required shrink then it's not an issue*" - If the 99% fragmentation doesn't mean anything in reality, then why does it matter to you?

Comment: Yes, resource contention isn't an outstanding concern in this case since there isn't a lot of pressure on the CPU, disk or things like AGs with large T-Log sizes to worry about. The only issue I encountered was a one-time larger T-Log backup due to the reorganize. I believe only external fragmentation is caused by a shrink (data pages out of order). I know internal fragmentation (page fill) benefits from index maintenance, and that external fragmentation is probably benign. But unless I can 100% confirm external fragmentation will not cause issues, I'm erring on the side of caution.

Comment: @Marcus Yikes, you have AGs in place too. Good luck, that's where stuff can get dicey with repeated heavy operations like this. "*But unless I can 100% confirm external fragmentation will not cause issues, I'm erring on the side of caution.*" - The experts (such as who I linked in my answer and people I've spoken to who work for Microsoft) will be as close to 100% as you're going to find, and their stance is the same as mine regarding fragmentation. It mattered to some degree before SSDs and NVMes, back when mechanical hard drives were the standard, but now it makes 0 difference.

Comment: Just to be clear I don't have AGs in place, otherwise I'd think twice about any index maintenance. I would still like to confirm through testing the impact, if any, of external fragmentation on SSDs, but it does seem like it's negligible so I'll probably stop it for now. As per Brent Ozar internal fragmentation still seems worth tackling for random deletes: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/index-fragmentation-matter/

Comment: @Marcus "*Just to be clear I don't have AGs in place*" - Ok, whew. "*As per Brent Ozar internal fragmentation still seems worth tackling for random deletes...*" - FWIW, that reference is over 7 years old, and states "*For most workloads, your best bet is still to analyze SQL Server wait statistics and understand the basic problem before you start defragmenting indexes on a regular basis.*". It also wasn't written by Brent Ozar who would probably agree that you don't need to routinely run index maintenance.

Comment: True, it was written by Jeremiah Peschka but it's still up so I assume it has/had Brent's approval. It's actually older than 7 years, most likely around 10, so maybe it's not very relevant anymore. Internal fragmentation does seem like it can cause a host of issues though, from fitting less data in memory to larger overall backups. Whether these issues are worth addressing depends on the environment's pain spots I imagine (in my case storage space). There was a comment on the page I linked (2nd from bottom) by Jeff Moden that pretty much blew me away. Will post it below as it won't fit.

Comment: Here's the comment – wondering if you have any insight on this, particularly the ever increasing indexes causing fragmentation point, because I understand that page splits should occur at the end of an index with an ascending key provided older rows aren't being deleted/updated. The comment:
To summarize, Random GUID fragmentation is a myth, ever increasing indexes are actually a hot spot for fragmentation, and using REORGANIZE is a nice way to perpetuate page splits and the resulting fragmentation all day every day.

Comment: @Marcus "*it's still up so I assume it has/had Brent's approval*" - Nah, it's still up because it's content for his website, regardless if his opinion differs now. I've found other old articles on his website which Brent disagrees with the premise on too (which I've confirmed by talking directly to Brent), yet they're still there. "*Here's the comment – wondering if you have any insight on this*" - I don't see any issues presented in that comment. All it says is here's a scenario that causes fragmentation and here's a way to remove that fragmentation. But it doesn't say what issues it causes.

Comment: @Marcus At the end of the day, I've spoken to multiple experts on this subject (many who browse here), including people who've worked for Microsoft and on the product, and the stance is all the same: Index Maintenance is wasteful and a waste.

Comment: I agree that most index maintenance is wasteful because it tends to be blind. But there are no hard and fast rules in the DB world. Internal fragmentation can be an issue for memory and storage. It really depends on the environment. Regarding the comment I was asking about, it was mostly how ever increasing indexes could be a hotspot for fragmentation. Afaik, page splits should only occur at the end of the index with an ever increasing key so this should never result in fragmentation.

Comment: "*Internal fragmentation can be an issue for memory and storage.*' - As much as a paper cut is a problem for long term heart health. Unfortunately I'm just going to have to disagree with you based on the fact that I've already spoken to multiple experts on this, and between that and my own decade of experience, there's no reason to be concerned with index fragmentation.

Comment: In an environment with a healthy storage and memory situation I agree with you, it's not gonna do much for your performance. But I think you're discounting that a lot of DBA's aren't working with ideal hardware. Surely in such environments, fitting more data into memory and ensuring your disks aren't at risk of reaching capacity are more pressing concerns than the occasional overhead of an index reorganize, especially if it's not something regular and doesn't cause issues with T-log growth.

Comment: @Marcus "*Surely in such environments, fitting more data into memory*" - If you're running out of Memory because of index fragmentation, then you have bigger problems, because that means your Memory is not sufficient for your currently architected system and will run out even if you had 0% fragmentation. It's such a small factor that it's negligible, even at 99% fragmentation. This means even your database is architected poorly or you're severely under-provisioned, but either way you're going to have worse problems, regardless of your index fragmentation situation.

Comment: "*ensuring your disks aren't at risk of reaching capacity*" - Index Maintenance will make you hit capacity faster since it increases your disk consumption by two-fold the size of your indexes. At some point when your indexes are using only half the disk (roughly) you will run out of space during index maintenance, the job will fail, and it was all a waste for blowing out your disk consumption. Then you'll be stuck. I don't believe shrinking will clean all of that up, but even if it did, now you're stuck unable to run index maintenance anyway when you get to half disk capacity.

Comment: @Marcus It just doesn't make sense. You're worrying about the wrong things. But that's up to you. Again, I'll defer to the multiple experts I've spoken to about this. I can assure you they know better here.

Comment: Regarding memory, the less that is taken up by pages resulting from page splits, the better. Data growth changes often outpace the speed with which you can upgrade your memory or rearchitect the system. I also wouldn't say it's as negligible factor as I was led to believe by the accepted answer for this post. I had a table around 20 GB in size, with around 10-20% empty space left by random deletes. Running a reorganize increased the available space in the DB by a little over 2 GB – that's significant.

Comment: Yes, architecture and hardware upgrades are good and should be done. But what if the above scenario happened to a table that you want always in memory? An approach to never defragment indexes would be leaving gigabytes of memory and potential performance on the table. Whereas a reorganize will net you performance gains in a matter of minutes, while architecture/hardware solutions could take days or weeks to implement, if at all.

Comment: Storage demands change over the course of a month in my environment. So if I need to deal with internal fragmentation, it would obviously be done during a low demand period. As I've reiterated, I'm not proposing blind index maintenance. But there are clearly situations where it can be of measurable benefit.

Comment: @Marcus "*But what if the above scenario happened to a table that you want always in memory?*" - It wouldn't be because it doesn't normally make sense to put an entire table in Memory. If you architected your database properly, you should be getting index seeks when your query runs. Only the data pages needed to suffice your query get loaded into memory - a minor subset of the entire table. Even at 99% fragmentation, that's still a small amount. At this point you haven't said anything unique to what you've already said, so I don't see any reason in carrying on. Again, the experts know best.

Comment: Yes, if databases are architected properly, and that's a big, big if. Assuming ideal conditions for hardware, architecture, etc. has been a far cry from what most databases systems I've worked with have been like. I don't think anything I've asserted has contradicted expert advice, and I think you'd be hard pressed to find one who would flat out say all index maintenance is useless. Appeals to authority are not convincing when empirical evidence to the contrary exists.

Comment: @Marcus "*Yes, if databases are architected properly, and that's a big, big if. Assuming ideal conditions for hardware, architecture*" - Architecting the database properly is something you are interested in, hence your question. So it's not a matter of "*if*". If the hardware so severely under-provisioned that what you're worrying about saving with index maintenance matters, then you're screwed anyway, because you'll have bigger problems with how little Memory and Disk Space is available, again, making it trivial to worry about index maintenance. Why focus on the littlest thing in such a case?

Comment: "*don't think anything I've asserted has contradicted expert advice, and I think you'd be hard pressed to find one who would flat out say all index maintenance is useless.*" - Wrong. I've already found multiple who frequent here, who completely agree. I've already had this conversation with them (not sure why I have to repeat myself here.) Some of which who've worked for Microsoft on the product. So I'm not sure why you persist, I've already refuted your points, and nothing you say will change the input of the experts I **already** have spoken to. Again, I see no need for you to reply anymore.